# How do I go about solving this algorithm?

Tags: javascript

I've been struggling with this question for a while now and have no idea how to go about it. The aim is to create unique device names. If a device already exists with a similar name, return an integer incremented by 1 for each occurrence.

Input: ['lamp', 'lamp', 'tv', 'lamp']

Expected Output: ['lamp', 'lamp1', 'tv', 'lamp2']

How should I go about this?

Answer (score 1):

You could create an object keyed by the original string, and with corresponding value a counter that starts at zero. Then perform a map of the original data by adding that counter (if it is non-zero) and at the same time incrementing that counter:

```js
let data = ['lamp', 'lamp', 'tv', 'lamp'];

let counters = Object.fromEntries(data.map(str => [str, 0]));
let result = data.map(str => str + (counters[str]++ || ""));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function myAlg(list){
    // You must create a memory in order to have the following index.
    var memo = {};
    // Let's create another result variable
    var newList = [];
    // Iterate the elements (there are only 2 casuistries)
    for(var elem of list){
        if(typeof memo[elem] === 'undefined'){
            memo[elem] = 0;
            newList.push(elem);
        } else {
            memo[elem]++;
            newList.push(elem+memo[elem]);
        }
    }
        return newList;
}
```

Comment: Good answers on Stack Overflow should explain the problem and how their solution solves it. Additionally, we expect the OP to have made an attempt at solving the problem and post their attempt, rather than just post requirements for a use case. If we answer such poor questions (that are likely to get closed because they are poor), we just attract more poor questions.